# How to get the post id from commentsController in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

this is about Laravel.
I would like to get post_id in the comment variable and store it to PHPMyAdmin, but I could not find proper code.

When I typed $comment->post_id = Posting::id(); in CommentsController, it generated error.
it showed "Call to undefined method App\Models\Posting::id()"

my code in CommentsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Comment;
use App\Models\Posting;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;


class CommentsController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('comments.create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'comment' => 'required',
        ]);


        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $comment = new Comment();
        //to store user_id
        $comment->user_id = Auth::id();
        //to store post_id

        //-----------------------------------------------------
        //Here is the problem I have right now.
        //I could not find proper code to store post_id in comment variable here.
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        h1$comment->post_id = ;
        //to store posting
        $comment->comment = $request->input('comment');
        //save all user input
        $comment->save();
        dd($request);
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

my code in PostingsController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\posting;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class PostingsController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //this is how to get all posting, but this shows only all posting
        // $postings = Posting::all();
        // $postings->load('user');
        //this is how to get all posting with created_at and descending order.
        $postings = Posting::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
        //should be function name
        $postings->load('user');


        return view('index')->with('postings', $postings);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        return view('create');
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'posting' => 'required',
        ]);

        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $posting = new Posting();
        //for connecting both user and posting
        $posting->user_id = Auth::id();
        //to store posting
        $posting->post = $request->input('posting');
        //save all user input
        $posting->save();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting created successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        return view('show')->with('posting', $posting);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //this is the way how to find posting of authenticated user
        $posting = Posting::find($id);

        return view('edit')->with('posting', $posting);
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //if user did not fill the form properly
        //error messages will popup
        $this->validate($request, [
            'posting' => 'required',
        ]);

        //if user filled the form properly
        //store the form
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        //to store posting
        $posting->post = $request->input('posting');
        //save all user input
        $posting->save();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting edited successfully!');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $posting = Posting::find($id);
        $posting->delete();

        return redirect()->to('/home')->with('success', 'Posting deleted successfully');
    }


}
```

I will update if there needs more information. Thank you in advance.

---Additional information---
this is comment model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Comment extends Model
{
    //comments has  only one post
    public function post(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Post::class, 'post_id');
    }


}
```

this is post model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Posting extends Model
{
    // For declaring postings has only one user in the model of users: 
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user_id');
    }
    // Posting has many comments
    public function comments(){
        return $this->HasMany(\App\Comment::class,'post_id');
    }


}
```

this is route list:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//when users hit my website, go to welcome.blade.php
Route::get('/', 'PostingsController@index');

//Auth::routes() is a helper class that helps you generate all the routes required for user authentication.
Auth::routes();
Route::resource('postings','PostingsController');
Route::resource('comments', 'CommentsController');

//Route::get('address_name', 'NameController');
//sometimes we deal with another one where I wrote 'HomeController@index'
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

+-----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Method    | URI                     | Action                                                                 |
+-----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GET|HEAD  | /                       | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@index                          |
| GET|HEAD  | api/user                | Closure                                                                |
| POST      | comments                | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@store                          |
| GET|HEAD  | comments                | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@index                          |
| GET|HEAD  | comments/create         | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@create                         |
| DELETE    | comments/{comment}      | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@destroy                        |
| PUT|PATCH | comments/{comment}      | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@update                         |
| GET|HEAD  | comments/{comment}      | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@show                           |
| GET|HEAD  | comments/{comment}/edit | App\Http\Controllers\CommentsController@edit                           |
| GET|HEAD  | home                    | App\Http\Controllers\HomeController@index                              |
| GET|HEAD  | login                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm                |
| POST      | login                   | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                        |
| POST      | logout                  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout                       |
| POST      | password/confirm        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@confirm            |
| GET|HEAD  | password/confirm        | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ConfirmPasswordController@showConfirmForm    |
| POST      | password/email          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@sendResetLinkEmail  |
| POST      | password/reset          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@reset                |
| GET|HEAD  | password/reset          | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ForgotPasswordController@showLinkRequestForm |
| GET|HEAD  | password/reset/{token}  | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm        |
| GET|HEAD  | postings                | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@index                          |
| POST      | postings                | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@store                          |
| GET|HEAD  | postings/create         | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@create                         |
| PUT|PATCH | postings/{posting}      | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@update                         |
| GET|HEAD  | postings/{posting}      | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@show                           |
| DELETE    | postings/{posting}      | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@destroy                        |
| GET|HEAD  | postings/{posting}/edit | App\Http\Controllers\PostingsController@edit                           |
| POST      | register                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register                  |
| GET|HEAD  | register                | App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm      |
+-----------+-------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you share your `Post` and `Comment` models? Also, your routes/web.php file.

Comment: which route brings you to 'CommentsController@store'?

Comment: yes I added models and routes list

Comment: Run `php artisan route:list --compact` and paste the output here.

Comment: You are trying to attach a new Comment to an existing Posting in the `CommentsController->store()` function, but a Posting ID cannot be retrieved. This leads to the question: how should the function know to which Posting the new Comment  should belong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the post_id in the request and then:

Inside Comment create/update views:

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_id" id="post_id" value="{{ $post->id }}" />
```

Inside Comment Controller:

```
//..
$comment->post_id = $request->input('post_id');
//..
```

Comment: then do I have to make a relation both post and comment?
if that case, post can have many comments and comments have only one post?

Comment: I assume that a comment has only 1 relations post_id field. So the db table should has this structure:

POSTS
id* ... etc

COMMENTS
id  post_id* ...etc